# Stripe Checkout Button Too Small on Mobile

Tags: html, css, stripe-payments

I feel like I must be missing something incredibly simple. Whenever I attempt to implement Stripe's Checkout feature on a mobile site, the payment button appears very, very small.

I stripped everything away that might be causing styling issues and then just started using their basic embedded form just to see and I still get this problem where it just doesn't appear optimized for a mobile format.

What am I missing here?

```
<html>
  <form id="buy" action="backend/create_subscription.php" method="post">
    <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="pk_test_SOMEKEYHERE"
      data-amount="2000"
      data-name="Widget"
      data-description="Some widget"
      data-image="/img/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-shipping-address="true"
      data-label="Option 1"
      data-panel-label="Subscribe"
      data-bitcoin="false">
    </script>
  </form>
</html>
```

[Image of the tiny button on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZmID.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a button issue, it's a scaling issue.  You might want to try this in your `<head>`:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

That should (probably?) help with scaling.  You could also do a [Custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) and that will allow you to use whatever button you want to trigger it.

Comment: Christ, of course. Must be tired over here. Thanks for the fast and spot on response!

Comment: You're welcome!  And I totally know the feeling... :)